# Wrapper to time generic function

Tags: c#, time, wrapper

I'm writing some code to generate a procedural map.
Some of the steps take much longer than others, and I'm timing each part of the build to see where the bottlenecks are, and to let the user know that the program hasn't stalled on them.

At the moment I have a lot of code that looks like this:

```
Console.Write("Creating tiles");
var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
CreateTiles();    //key mapgen function
watch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("... finished in: {0} s", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds/1000d);

Console.Write("Calculating tile elevations");
var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
CalculateTileElevations();    //key mapgen function
watch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("... finished in: {0} s", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds/1000d);
//etc
```

My question is, is there a way of refactoring this to look something more like the following:

```
ExecuteTimedFunction(CreateTiles(), "Creating tiles");
ExecuteTimedFunction(CalculateTileElevations(), "Calculating tile elevations");

void ExecuteTimedFunction(Func genericFunction, String logMsg)
{
    Console.Write(logMsg);
    var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
    genericFunction();    
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("... finished in: {0} s", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds/1000d);
}
```

Caveat: the return type of all of the functions is `void` as they all manipulate a master list of tiles, but not all of the functions have the same number of input parameters (although the majority have 0 parameters so a solution for that case would still be useful)

Comment: If you change the type of `genericFunction` to `Action` it should work. Then you can call it like `ExecuteTimedFunction(CreateTiles, "Creating tiles");`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `ExecuteTimedFunction` method would look something like this:

```
public void ExecuteTimedFunction(Action action, string name)
{
    Console.Write(name);
    var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    action();
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("... finished in: {0} s", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds/1000d);
}
```

Then you can call it in either of the following ways:

```
ExecuteTimedFunction(MyFunctionWithNoParams, "MyFunc");
ExecuteTimedFunction(() => MyFuncWithParams(p1, p2), "MyFunc2");
```

Comment: Awesome, this works exactly as I would like. Can anyone recommend an introductory source on `Action` and similar?

Comment: Possibly _the_ source? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx :)

Comment: the MSDN isn't always the most novice-friendly place for new things but I'll give it a go :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also access the called method details for logging by changing it into something like:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{action.Method.Name} finished in: {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000d} s");
```

Comment: this is cool, but some of the functions have complex subroutines that are either timed themselves, or show a % complete etc, so I'd like to have the 'function started' printed before the method actually runs