# Determining function time using a wrapper

Tags: c++, function, templates

I'm looking for a generic way of measuring a functions timing like [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39491175/wrapper-to-time-generic-function), but for c++.

My main goal is to not have cluttered code like this piece everywhere:

```
  auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  function(arg1, arg2);
  auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  auto tDur = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2 - t1);
```

But rather have a nice wrapper around the function.
What I got so far is:

timing.hpp:

```
#pragma once

#include <chrono>
#include <functional>

template <typename Tret, typename Tin1, typename Tin2> unsigned int getDuration(std::function<Tret(Tin1, Tin2)> function, Tin1 arg1, Tin2 arg2, Tret& retValue)
{
  auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  retValue = function(arg1, arg2);
  auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  auto tDur = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2 - t1);
  return tDur.count();
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "timing.hpp"
#include "matrix.hpp"

constexpr int G_MATRIXSIZE = 2000;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
CMatrix<double> myMatrix(G_MATRIXSIZE);

bool ret;
// this call is quite ugly
std::function<bool(int, std::vector<double>)> fillRow = std::bind(&CMatrix<double>::fillRow, &myMatrix, 0, fillVec);
auto duration = getDuration(fillRow, 5, fillVec, ret );
std::cout << "duration(ms): " << duration << std::endl;
}
```

in case sb wants to test the code, matrix.hpp:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T> class CMatrix {
public:
    // ctor
    CMatrix(int size) :
        m_size(size)
    {
        m_matrixData = new std::vector<std::vector<T>>;
        createUnityMatrix();
    }
    // dtor
    ~CMatrix()
    {
        std::cout << "Destructor of CMatrix called" << std::endl;
        delete m_matrixData;
    }
    
    // print to std::out
    void printMatrix()
    {
        std::ostringstream oss;
        for (int i = 0; i < m_size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m_size; j++)
            {
                oss << m_matrixData->at(i).at(j) << ";";
            }
            oss << "\n";
        }
        std::cout << oss.str() << std::endl;
    }

    bool fillRow(int index, std::vector<T> row)
    {
        // checks
        if (!indexValid(index))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (row.size() != m_size)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // data replacement
        for (int j = 0; j < m_size; j++)
        {
            m_matrixData->at(index).at(j) = row.at(j);
        }
        return true;
    }

    bool fillColumn(int index, std::vector<T> column)
    {
        // checks
        if (!indexValid(index))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (column.size() != m_size)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // data replacement
        for (int j = 0; j < m_size; j++)
        {
            m_matrixData->at(index).at(j) = column.at(j);
        }
        return true;
    }

private:
    // variables
    std::vector<std::vector<T>>* m_matrixData;
    int m_size;

    bool indexValid(int index)
    {
        if (index + 1 > m_size)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    // functions
    void createUnityMatrix()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < m_size; i++)
        {
            std::vector<T> _vector;
            for (int j = 0; j < m_size; j++)
            {
                if (i == j)
                {
                    _vector.push_back(1);
                }
                else
                {
                    _vector.push_back(0);
                }
            }
            m_matrixData->push_back(_vector);
        }
    }
};
```

The thing is, this code is still quite ugly due to the std::function usage. Is there a better and/or simpler option ?
(+ also I'm sure I messed sth up with the std::bind, I think I need to use std::placeholders since I want to set the arguments later on.)

// edit, correct use of placeholder in main:

```
std::function<bool(int, std::vector<double>)> fillRow = std::bind(&CMatrix<double>::fillRow, &myMatrix, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
  auto duration = getDuration(fillRow, 18, fillVec, ret );
```

Comment: A problem with the "nice wrapper" is that you are now timing a wrapped function, which likely has more overhead than a non-wrapped function. Different amount of inlining comes to mind.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about this yet. Though generally I am only interested in the timing of functions that take **significantly** longer than the overhead so I can live with this drawback.

Comment: You know that you can use a profiler which give you the same information and a lot more statistics. No need t write mappers...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can utilize RAII to implement a timer that records the execution time of a code block and a template function that wraps the function you would like to execute with the timer.

```cpp
#include<string>
#include<chrono>
#include <unistd.h>

struct Timer
{
    std::string fn, title;
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> start;
    Timer(std::string fn, std::string title)
        : fn(std::move(fn)), title(std::move(title)), start(std::chrono::steady_clock::now())
    {
    }
    ~Timer()
    {
        const auto elapsed =
            std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start).count();
        printf("%s: function=%s; elasepd=%f ms\n", title.c_str(), fn.c_str(), elapsed / 1000.0);
    }
};

#ifndef ENABLE_BENCHMARK
static constexpr inline void dummy_fn() { }
#define START_BENCHMARK_TIMER(...) dummy_fn()
#else
#define START_BENCHMARK_TIMER(title) bench::Timer timer(__FUNCTION__, title)
#endif

template<typename F, typename ...Args>
auto time_fn(F&& fn, Args&&... args) {
  START_BENCHMARK_TIMER("wrapped fn");
  return fn(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int foo(int i) {
  usleep(70000);
  return i;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", time_fn(foo, 3));
}
```

stdout:

```
wrapped fn: function=time_fn; elasepd=71.785000 ms
3
```

General Idea:

1. `time_fn` is a simple template function that calls `START_BENCHMARK_TIMER` and calls `fn` with the provided arguments
2. `START_BENCHMARK_TIMER` then creates a `Timer` object. It will record the current time in `start`. Do note that `__FUNCTION__` will be replaced with the function that was called.
3. When the
   provided `fn` returns or throws an exception, the `Timer` object from (1) will be destroyed and the destructor will be called. The destructor will then calculate the time difference between the current time and the recorded `start` time and prints it to stdout

Note:

- Even though declaring `start` and `end` in `time_fn` instead of the RAII timer will work, having an RAII timer will allow you to cleanly handle the situation when `fn` throws an exception
- If you are on c++11, you will need to change `time_fn` declaration to `typename std::result_of<F &&(Args &&...)>::type  time_fn(F&& fn, Args&&... args)`.

Edit: Updated the response to include a wrapper function approach.

Comment: I like this RAII approach. I'd prefer a wrapper, but this is perfectly plausible and very simple to use. The only reason to use a #define is to get the function name, correct ?
Going to wait one more day to see if sb comes up with a wrapper-approach, otherwise I will accept this answer.

Comment: @MAPster Are you using a C++20 compiler? If so, you can do without `#define` too by using [`std::source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location). Here's an [example](https://godbolt.org/z/69E95b8cb). I don't think `clang++`'s standard library supports it yet, even in C++20 mode though.

Comment: @MAPster the main motivation of using the MACRO is to prevent the unnecessary declaration of `Timer` and it will also allow you to toggle the timer with a compilation flag. I also my answer with a wrapper function approach.

Comment: Note: You do not need `duration_cast` or `/ 1000` if you do `const auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start).count();` instead. It's then a `double` holding the number of milliseconds it took.

Comment: ... and you could also use a macro to enable benchmarking and still get the benefit from `std::source_location`. It's rather convenient and gives better info than `__FUNCTION__` etc. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/xvx63TKer)

Comment: @KlementTan Nice, your answer now features a few tweaks I have to think a bit about but it's exactly what I wanted. Thanks =D

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks I already stumbled upon this when I was ranting about some logging implementations ^^ Guess now it's time to have a deeper dive into it, your input is much appreciated.